# Ruby self method not setup properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I think I'm close to getting the right syntax on the method below, but I'm not quite these.  I always get confused as to when to use the "self" method.  Here's the context: the method below is meant to compare a file saved to the database against a file currently on a website.  The method itself is a member of a model class in a rails app.

But when I run the code in the console, it gets stuck on the "self."  It can't call the versions method on a nil class.  What am I misunderstanding about the "self"?  What do I need to do to make this method work?

```
    def compare
      live_file = download_file
      archive_file = self.versions.last.changeset[:robots_file]
      if live_file != archive_file
        return mismatch
      end 
    end
```

Edit: Here's the error message I get in console.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `versions' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/bendowney/sites/WatchApp/app/models/site.rb:14:in `compare'
from (irb):50
from /Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@WatchApp/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@WatchApp/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@WatchApp/gems/railties-3.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

EDIT: Answer is below.

Comment: Are you trying to call this on an actual instance of this class, or are you attempting to call it statically as in `model_instance.compare` vs `YourModel.compare`

Comment: I don't think your problem is with "self"; I think it's with the way the compare method itself is getting called.  Can you show us an example of setting up an instance of the containing class and calling the method?

Comment: I'm calling the method like this model_instance.compare, e.g. "@file.compare"

Comment: Can  you post the actual stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You all ask the right questions. They got me thinking. I made two changes to my original method and now it works. I needed to save the file I downloaded (line 2 below) and I had a forgot to encapsulate my "mismatch" status in quotation marks. Thanks for your help!

```
def compare
  live_file = download_robots_file
  self.save
  archive_file = self.versions.last.changeset[:robots_file]
  if live_file != archive_file
    return "mismatch"
  end 
end
```